# How to use KeyPress event in textBox with Tab character?

Tags: c#, key

```
   private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Tab)
        {
            keybox4.Focus();
        }
    }
```

It not working but enter character its Working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to have the `MultiLine` property set to `true`, and [`AcceptsTab`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.acceptstab.aspx) also set to `true`.